# Option to set number of pages while generating pdf using xdocreport

Tags: java, pdf, velocity, xdocreport

Is there any option to set number of pages while converting odt -> pdf using xdocreport?

I want the number of pages parameter to be configurable based on the content of the document being generated.

If the number of pages in the document is 1 then add one blank page, if length is 3 then add one.
So basically I want to generate document with even number of pages and it is fine if last page is blank.

The content in the document will be added dynamically so I can't just pass the number of pages using some config parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The XDocReport odt->pdf converter manages page number automatically. It generates pdf which follow the same pages than odt. There is no way to configure it.